# How to handle html code in a MQSL Replace

Tags: html, mysql, replace

I have a Wordpress DB where I embeded advertising in the post as HTML manually when the posts were written. Like this but I have changed the URLS a bit :)

```
<div style="float: left;"><a href="http://xx-xx.com/c/xxx/xx/xxx">
<img alt="" src="http://xxx.xxx.com/display-ad/xxx-3xxx" border="2" />
```

This was all manually added when the posts were written and instead of being smart and calling another DB for the HTML to be inserted it was hard coded into the posts!

Now instead of removing it all manually I would like to use the REPLACE command or something smarter?

I guess I could use something like this below instead but they are not all written exactly the same and I cant find anything to actually catch thats not elsewhere other than the url. I have used this below alot.

```
UPDATE `xxxx_wordpress`.`wp_posts` SET post_content = if(instr(post_content,"<p>xxxxx")>0,substr(post_content,instr(post_content,"<p>xxxx</p>") + 25, instr(post_content,"<p>xxxx</p>")-instr(post_content,"<p>xxx</p>") - 25),post_content)
```

But can you simply use the REPLACE command because when I tried it the special characters broke the query.

Any better ideas?

Comment: why don't you scape the special characters using replace?

Comment: How? I was not able to get it to work... thats why I asked because it killed the mysql sql query.